# Using IDTech UniPay Card Reader with Cordova/PhoneGap

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

After installing this plugin: https://github.com/TranWare/cordova-plugins which should work with this device: http://www.idtechproducts.com/products/mobile-readers/176.html
I am trying to use it but when I called it "IDTech is not defined" even I saw the plugin running on debug mode!

Answer (score 1):

Are you developing for Android or iOS (or both)?

Looking at the source of this plugin, its Android only. Unfortunately, it looks like nobody has written a proper Cordova plugin for the IDTech card reader that supports both platforms :(

I did find another plugin, but this one is iOS only: https://github.com/deboorn/iMag-Cordova-Plugin. Maybe give that one a shot instead?

I should note I've not tried either of these plugins personally, but I am doing some research in adding support for this device in a Cordova app I've built and came across that plugin (and your post). Best of luck!